# Unable to call $scope function in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this function `showPopupSelectTopic(subject)` to call in my `ng-repeat` html code. But it does not work at all.

```
         <div style="width:100%;" ng-controller="manageStudyCtrl">
            <div class="div-subject" ng-repeat="subject in dataSubject" ng-click="showPopupSelectTopic(subject)">  
                <div class="round-button-subject-2">
                    <div class="subject-name-2 subject-eng" style="color:{{subject.subject_code.colour_code}}">
                        {{subject.subject_code.short_name}}
                        <div>{{subject.avg_overall_coverage | number : 0}}%</div>
                    </div>
                    <circular-progress
                        value = "subject.avg_overall_coverage"
                        max="100"
                        orientation="1"
                        radius="36"
                        stroke="8"
                        base-color="#b9b9b9"
                        progress-color="{{subject.subject_code.colour_code}}"
                        iterations="100"
                        animation="easeInOutCubic"
                    ></circular-progress>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

I want to call my `showPopupSelectTopic(subject)`in my controller so that I can make popup and manipulate the data.

I have done outside from `ng-repeat`and its working perfectly. However if I used in `ng-repeat` then it would not execute as expected. How to solve this issue?

---

My controller:

```
angular.module('manageStudy', [])
.controller('manageStudyCtrl', function($scope,){

$scope.showPopupSelectTopic = function(subject) {
    alert(subject.chapter_id);
};
});
```

Comment: Check for correct naming of function in controller: `$scope.showPopupSelectTopic`.

Comment: That won't be possible or work properly, since every ng-repeat is creating its own child scope. You'd have to access their parent scope.

Comment: @Aer0 so how to do that?

Comment: @Mahmoud I've checked and it was same but still not working at all

Comment: can you paste your controller code ?

Comment: @Angular_10 I've updated my question.

Comment: Your controller doesn't show how dataSubject is filled with objects on which you need to repeat

Comment: I agreed with @Angular_10 for answer http://plnkr.co/edit/lEEPxYDhWmwH4WdNsneO?p=preview. My problem was I try to click at all the divs, but it just only working at top of the border of each iteration. I do not know what to do since first row was ok (with only top border) but at second row, the function could not be called.

Comment: I solved the problems by modify my z-index to be higher. So the function could be click by the user as expected. Thank you guys for any help.

Comment: I got the answer with another way. Not exact problem with angular but with CSS3 only.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible due to every ng-repeat creating its own child scope. That being said, ever functio invocation will lead the child to copy some variables into its own scope. You'd have to use their parentscope or refere to the origin `$scope` of your controller.

```
ng-click="$parent.showPopupSelectTopic(subject)"
```

This should solve the problem. However, it's kinda dirty. A better solution would be to return your parents scope and use it in every child scope just like that. So declare a function inside of your controller (e.g. `$scope.getScope`) and let it simply return its `$scope`. Afterwards you'll be able to access it properly.

```
$scope.getScope = function() {
  return $scope;
}

ng-click = "getScope().showPopupSelectTopic(subject)"
```

Comment: I don't agree with using $parent to access function in ng-click please refer to @Larry Turtis answer https://plnkr.co/edit/lEEPxYDhWmwH4WdNsneO?p=preview  with example ! There is no need to use it unless u are deep dived in with nested controllers

Comment: @Angular_10 I just mentioned that it's possible. I've also provided a better solution.

Comment: Is it I just paste `ng-click = "getScope().showPopupSelectTopic(subject)"` to my DOM?

Comment: @Imran After assigning the function `$scope.getScope = function() ...` to your controller, yes, that should hopefully do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

ng-repeat works only with an iterate able object, like array or collection. Before you open the div where you intent to repeat, the iterate able object must be in ready in the scope. Try using ngInit instead of ngClick to initialize the array before attempting to ngRepeat

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: check the documentation of how to use ngRepeat [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)